# Magento user permission unchecked on save custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, user-roles

I've developed a small custom module.
It worked as expected but I can't save user permission:
I can see the module in the admin panel and in the Role Resource Tab
(System->Permissions->Roles), but when I tried to check the module and save the user role, it will say that it has been saved. But when I rechecked the user role, it is still unchecked.

> adminhtml.xml:

```
 <menu>
    <Gestion translate="title" module="Gestion_Commande">
        <title>Navette</title>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <children>
            <envoi>
                <title>Preparation Magasin Cursol</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/gestion/envoi</action>
            </envoi>
            <receptio>
                <title>Reception Begles</title>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/gestion/reception</action>
            </receptio>
            <crossdoc>
                <title>Crossdocking et Erreurs De Stock</title>
                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/gestion/crossdoc</action>
            </crossdoc>
        </children>
    </Gestion>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <Gestion translate="title" module="Gestion_Commande">
                    <title>Navette</title>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <envoi>
                            <title>Preparation Magasin Cursol</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </envoi>
                        <receptio>
                            <title>Reception Begles</title>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        </receptio>
                        <crossdoc>
                            <title>Crossdocking et Erreurs De Stock</title>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        </crossdoc>
                    </children>
                </Gestion>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

I've seen this post, but it doesn't seem to be the same problem

[Can't Save Role Resource for Custom Module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/737/cant-save-role-resource-for-custom-module)

any ideas?

**EDIT**

Now access are granted successfully, but when I rechecked the user role, it is still unchecked...